# why take a empty Xamarin Android app about 10mb space?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i tryed Xamarin on my android smartphone and install the default "Hello world Button Click" app on it. This empty app take 9,3mb on my smartphone and i wondering if it's  normal for a android app? Maybe i done something wrong and can deleate something from the default project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xamarin apps have to package the .NET runtime with each individual app. Debug versions of the app are by default bigger; release versions should be smaller, and there are techniques you can use to minimize their size further.

This is discussed in detail [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/).